# Shiny: Align text in textInput

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app with an input field (textInput). I would like to align the input text to the right. In CSS it would be something like `text-align: right;`. Does someone have an idea I can do this?

You can find a code example below.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("text", "Enter your text here")
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$value <- renderText({ input$text })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Do you want the `textInput` field should come at right side or the insertion of text from right side in `textInput` ?

Comment: The insertion of text should be from right side in `textInput`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there should've been a way to add a style argument to `textInput` so that you could pass `style="text-align: right"` to `textInput`. Anyways here's one way -

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  HTML(
    '<div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
      <label for="text">Enter text here</label>
      <input id="text" type="text" style="text-align: right" class="form-control" value=""/>
      </div>'
  ),
  textOutput("value")
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$value <- renderText({
    input$text
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The way I did this was just get the output for `textInput("text", "Enter your text here")` in console and manually added the `style` attribute to `<input>`. For repeated use you could turn this into a function and call it `right_textInput()` or something.

[image]

---

Another way is to add `css` to your `inputId`, in this case `#text`. However you'll have to do this for every `textInput` that you want to right align -

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML("#text text-align: right")))
  textInput("text", "Enter text here"),
  textOutput("value")
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$value <- renderText({
    input$text
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the `textInput` at right side of `fluidRow`, use below example.

```
    library(shiny)
    ui <- fluidPage(
      fluidRow(textInput("text", "Enter your text here"), align = 'right')
    )
    server <- function(input, output) {
      sampleText <- renderText({input$text })
    }
    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can apply css, see https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html
In the HTML the text input should have an ID of 'text